# SD card Mounting

Tags: mount

I have a 128 GB SSD, and I was looking into external storage devices. I know how to mount a flash drive, but I was wondering if it's the same process with an SD card?

Do SD cards auto-mount, where you then have to go into GParted, unmount, and set up a new mount-point into a desired folder? Or is it a completely different process than flash drives?

Thank you.

Comment: It will mount like a flash drive and will mount with its label usually under `/media/username/<drive label or UUID if no drive label is used>` that is if you are plugging it in as a USB .. if you have a card reader then .. well that's usually plugged in via usb internally so .. same process

Comment: @JohnOrion Yah, it has a separate slot for SD cards. So it will mount it just like a flash drive?

Comment: yeah .. if it has a label it will mount as the label name just like a USB an if it doesn't have a label it will use the UUID so it would be a long number.. but basically its just like a USB

Comment: Many times, sdcards will be listed as `mmcblkN` (ex mmcblk0) under /dev/.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount any block storage device. They include your HDD, SSD, CD/DVD, Memory Card, USB, any flash storage, etc.

To mount it, you can use the `mount` command. You don't have to use GParted to mount devices every time.